# How do I disable my login button in python

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter

Only added a small bit that im stuck on. I want to disable the loginButton when a new file for the database is made which is empty. I hoped this will work but I get

```
TypeError:'NoneType' object doesn't support item assignment
```

Please help

```
# moves username and password to another function 
Login = partial(login, username, password)

# this is the button that I want to disable as it will through errors as there isnt any data in the file to compare with

loginButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Login", command=Login).grid(row=4, column=0)

# checks if the file is empty and when it is then it meant to disable the button but instead I get the error listed above

if os.path.getsize('accounts.txt') ==0:
    state = loginButton.DISABLED
else:
  # when the file has data then it will enable it.

    loginButton['state']= 'normal'
    pass
```

any suggestions?

Comment: everything else works except for this

Comment: Well, you assigned `None` to `loginButton` - the return value of the `.grid()` method.  You need to call that method as a separate statement if you want to store the Button itself in a variable.

Comment: Ok, never knew that so your telling me that the .grid() changes the value to None? So that explains why my other code didnt work.

Comment: so would i do something like loginB= Button(tkWindow, text="Login", command=Login) and then  loginButton = loginB.grid(row=4, column=0) ??

Comment: There is no point whatsoever in assigning the result of `.grid()` to a variable, since it's always going to be `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Login = partial(login, username, password)

loginButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Login", command=Login)
loginButton.grid(row=4, column=0)

if os.path.getsize('accounts.txt') == 0:
    loginButton['state'] = DISABLED
else:
    loginButton['state'] = NORMAL
    pass
```

Comment: Would love to but I get   "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Cant believe it was as easy as that. had to delete 100 lines in my other code to do the same to find out that it still doesnt work. Thanks for the help

Comment: the prob in ur code was cuz u wer saying `.grid(...)` in the same line as ur definition of the label thats why it says `None`. It is a good practice to `.grid()` in the next line rather than the same line :D